# iOS Card.io SDK will allow user enter the name manually?

Tags: ios, iphone, card.io

Currently I am using card.io SDK in my app here I want to user enter the card holder name, But card.io library enter manually view didn't have the name text filled

Is there is any way to make it available the card holder name text field?

Note: it's available in Android

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just set [collectCardholderName](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/blob/master/CardIO/CardIOPaymentViewController.h#L131)

So in the [scanCard](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/blob/master/SampleApp-Swift/SampleApp-Swift/ViewController.swift#L25) function, just set it to true:

```
@IBAction func scanCard(sender: AnyObject) {
    let cardIOVC = CardIOPaymentViewController(paymentDelegate: self)
    cardIOVC.modalPresentationStyle = .FormSheet
    cardIOVC.collectCardholderName = true
    presentViewController(cardIOVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```